# Issue with contact form displaying sent message on php rather than in html page

Tags: php, forms, message, display, contacts

So I have tried searching for this issue and have tried many fixes but I still keep getting the same issue, "Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!" displays on php page rather than on the contact form html page, Im sure there is something very simple that I'm missing, I keep ending in stupid thought and search loops, I thank you all for any help you can offer.

```js
$(function() {
  // init the validator
  // validator files are included in the download package
  // otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

  $("#contact-form").validator();

  // when the form is submitted
  $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(e) {
    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      var url = "ebsg.php";

      // FOR CODEPEN DEMO I WILL PROVIDE THE DEMO OUTPUT HERE, download the PHP files from
      // https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

      var messageAlert = "alert-success";
      var messageText =
        "Your message was sent, thank you. ebgs will get back to you soon.";

      // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
      var alertBox =
        '<div class="alert ' +
        messageAlert +
        ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
        messageText +
        "</div>";

      // If we have messageAlert and messageText
      if (messageAlert && messageText) {
        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
        $("#contact-form").find(".message").html(alertBox);
        // empty the form
        $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
      }

      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
<?php
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => '6LelY04iAAAAAN',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

// configure
$from = 'ebsg contact form <ebsg@domain.com>';
$sendTo = 'ebsg contact form <email@yahoo.co.uk>';
$subject = 'ebsg contact form message';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Address', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from ebsg website contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
    }
?>
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="ebsg.php" role="form">

                       

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="form_lastname">Address *</label>
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your address *" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for EBSG *" rows="4" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="message"></div>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lel478655677AACWfJGw0i2SDE9B-dbr-5mD6OHqG"></div>
                                
                               

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p class="text-muted justify-content-center"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: It is unclear what the relation between the 3 sections of code is. Are they all from the same file?

Comment: Is there supposed to be some code which sends the form data via ajax? That seems to be missing.

Comment: _Side note:_ When adding code to your question, please only add HTML, CSS and JS as "HTML/CSS/JS"-snippets. And only do it for code that can be executed and tested directly in the browser (complete examples). If you add other languages (like PHP) as a "HTML/CSS/JS" snippet, it won't be correctly syntax highlighted, making it harder to read. You can read more about formatting here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: the issue is  the JS script is opening a php page instead of displaying ""Your message was sent, thank you. ebgs will get back to you soon." on the HTML, sorry for my mistakes

Comment: The JS code isn't doing that, the JS code just attempts to validate your form. The form's "action" method is what's causing the postback to the PHP script, as per its default behaviour. Which bit of the code do you think is supposed to display that on the HTML? Like I said above, if you want to send the data to PHP, and get back the response so that it can be shown on the same HTML page that the request came from, you'll need to make an asynchronous AJAX request using Javascript, instead of just doing a standard postback. But there's nothing in the code you've shown which does that task.

Comment: P.S. There's a comment in your JS code, with a link to this URL: https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form . If you look at the actual code they've used there, you can compare it to yours. Note their use of an AJAX request, and your lack of one. If you were trying to follow that tutorial, it's unclear why you took that bit out (or didn't copy it into your version).

Comment: @ADyson thanks man, thank you for taking time to look and help, much appreciated